# Code inside script in JSP is not getting refreshed at interval

Tags: javascript, jsp, highcharts

I am using high chart for plotting dynamic graph. For this I am calling function to get the last data after 1000 ms. But the same code is shown on graph.  alert also show the same data.

The code is

```
load: function() {
           var series = this.series[0];
                            setInterval(function() {          
               <% Livedynamicgraph l = new Livedynamicgraph(); %>                 
               var   x = <%out.println(l.gettime()); %> ;
                  alert(x)  
                  y = <%out.println(l.getresponsetime()); %>; 
                 series.addPoint([x, y], true, true); 
                       }, 1000);
```

Comment: This is not the way to get updated data from server. You need to use AJAX magic to achieve what you want.

Comment: can u reply me detail . how to implement ajax in high chart in jsp

Comment: What is Livedynamicgraph? Is it a Servlet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax

Comment: In other words, this: `<%out.println(l.gettime()); %>` is done only once, when page is loaded. See Highcharts [tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) for this. Check first point - it's done in PHP, you need to do the same in JSP.